# Django Model filters

Tags: python, django, filter, many-to-many, django-queryset

I have the following Models in a Django Project:

```
class Accion(models.Model):
   nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank = True, null=True)

class Proyecto(models.Model):
   titulo = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank = True, null=True)
   acciones = models.ManyToManyField(Accion,blank = True, null=True,related_name="Proyectos")
```

I need to get all Accion objects related with a list of ids of Proyecto objects in a reversed filter() query.
I tried this:

```
ids_Proyecto=Proyecto.values_list('id').filter(titulo__icontains='ejemplo')
list_acciones=Accion(proyectos__id__in=ids_Proyecto)
```

But I get the following error: 
**'proyectos_*id*_in' is an invalid keyword argument for this function**

How can i get the Accion objects queryset? Thankss

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the line to:

```
list_acciones=Accion.objects.filter(proyectos__id__in=ids_Proyecto)
```

See [Retrieving specific objects with filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters) for more details on how to use filter queries.

Comment: I think ```list_acciones=Accion.objects.filter(proyectos_id__in=ids_Proyecto)``` can work better but I am not sure .